# Resize table with react

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, reactjs

How can I turn a responsive desk with reacting, I have a problem, when I increase the screen the table not resize.
This is my code.

```
class Users extends Component {
   render() {
  const styles = {
  tableStyles: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
};
return (
  <Wrapper>
    <Table
      style={styles.tableStyles}
      columns={columns}
      data={users}
      border
      highlightCurrentRow
      onCurrentChange={item => { console.log(item) }}
      emptyText={`A carregar utilizadores`}
    />
    }
  </Wrapper >
)
```

}
}

Comment: render() {  const tableStyles = {width: '100%'}  ...... }

Comment: Sorry, I suposed people can understood I wrote well, now is everynthing.

Comment: it all depends on other elements/components style - inspect rendered html - it's not react-related